# Tkinter Entry widget in Python is uneditable

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, filedialog

When I run this code, the file picker comes up, and then when I finish with it, I can't type in the entry widget until I focus on another window and then come back. Why is this happening?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


location = ''
start = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(text='What is the name of your table?').pack()
box = tk.Entry(start, exportselection=0, state=tk.DISABLED)
box.pack()
button = tk.Button(start, text='OK', command=lambda e: None)
button.pack()
location = askopenfilename(defaultextension='.db', 
                           title="Choose your database", 
                           filetypes=[('Database Files', '.db'), ('All files', '*')])
box.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

start.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you running this on OSX?

Comment: I don't have a clue why, but I suppose you could do the askopenfilename first then mainloop start...

Comment: I'm not on OSX, I'm on Windows 7 & 8.1. And how could I make the mainloop not start until the askopenfilename window is closed?

Comment: To not run the mainloop until the askopenfilename is closed is nearly impossible as it always needs a root or primary window so you could possibly create a temp one and do root.withdraw()

Comment: The entry widget thing could possibly be a bug within Python 2 so I would consider updating to Python 3 and using that tkinter in there.

Comment: @ddsnowboard did you find a solution to the above issue. I am currently working on something similar, and this is where i  am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You just write `box.focus_force()` below `box.pack()` and that should do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow 2 steps:

1. Write `box.focus_force()` below `box.pack()`.
2. Cut the code `location = askopenfilename(blah blah..)` and paste it after `start = tk.Tk()`

You will be good to go!

Answer (score -1):

This should fix it

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
location = ''
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
location = askopenfilename(defaultextension='.db', title="Choose your database", filetypes=[('Database Files', '.db'), ('All files', '*')])
start = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(start, text='What is the name of your table?').pack()
box = tk.Entry(start, exportselection=0, state=tk.DISABLED)
box.pack()
start.focus_set()
box.focus_set()
start.focus_force()
button = tk.Button(start, text='OK', command=lambda e: None)
button.pack()
box.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
start.mainloop()
```

By running the `askopenfilename` first you can avoid this issue.

In doing it this way you need to make a `root` window and withdraw it or you will get two windows.

By using `focus_set` and `focus_force` you can make the box immediately ready to use.

Comment: This did not solve the issue. I am working on something similar and this is still giving trouble. You have any other idea?